# How to process multi-line text in Spark

Tags: python, scala

Suppose I have a dictionary with words and explanations in the following format:

```
Firefox

    <web> A complete {free}, {open-source} {web
    browser} from the {Mozilla Foundation} and therefore a true
    code descendent of {Netscape Navigator}.  The first non-{beta
    release} was in late 2004.

    {Firefox Home (http://mozilla.org/products/firefox)}.

    (2005-01-26)

firehose syndrome

    <networking, jargon> An absence, failure or inadequacy of flow
    control mechanisms causing the sender to overwhelm the
    receiver.  The implication is that, like trying to drink from
    a firehose, the consequenses are worse than just loss of data,
    e.g. the receiver may {crash}.

    See {ping-flood}.

    [{Jargon File}]

    (2007-03-12)

firewall

    1. {firewall code}.

    2. {firewall machine}.

firewall code

    1. The code you put in a system (say, a telephone switch) to
    make sure that the users can't do any damage. Since users
    always want to be able to do everything but never want to
    suffer for any mistakes, the construction of a firewall is a
    question not only of defensive coding but also of interface
    presentation, so that users don't even get curious about those
    corners of a system where they can burn themselves.

    2. Any sanity check inserted to catch a {can't happen} error.
    Wise programmers often change code to fix a bug twice: once to
    fix the bug, and once to insert a firewall which would have
    arrested the bug before it did quite as much damage.

    [{Jargon File}]
```

How would I map this type of data so that I can do things with it in spark?

Comment: You could you regular expression in order to generate an a case class with all relevant definitions. What would you like to keep? For instance, every line that doesn't start with \t is a new word definition.

Comment: @z-star I'd like to keep the word, and the definitions section per word (which from there, I can re-map and put into their own RDDs based on type of content)

Comment: Well. When I think about it. It does not make sense to read this file in a distributed fashion as its line order impacts the logic. The easy solution would be to pre process the dictionary so that each line will hold the word and its definition. It would be almost impossible to do this by distributed transformation of the data. Just right a short script the preprocess this dictionary as mentioned.